# Navigate options in command line

Tags: java

Is there something i can use so i can display a list of options, and the user navigates the list with arrows and then select any option? I've seen a lot of java programs run in cmd, and they give you a list so you can select an option by pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to first print out all your choices:

```
List<String> choices = Arrays.asList("choice1", "choice2", "chice3");

for (int i=0; i<choices.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(i+" : "+choices.get(i));
}
```

Then ask the user to enter his choice:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);   
System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
int n = reader.nextInt();
```

Comment: is there any chance the user can navigate the options with up and down arrows, and select an option with enter?